# Working out distance from original point when rotating around axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So, I am writing some code for a system that connects two points together with a line. The line's length is calculated, and then drawn on the canvas, as shown in the image below:

[image: image prompt]

As shown in the image, I am wanting to work out the length of 'b'. How would I go about doing this? What formula would I need to use?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how I will resolve this? It's preventing me from progressing with my programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(x,y)$, as in your picture. The line you have labeled $AB$ connects $A$ with $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)$, so the center of the line segment is at $(\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)$. In the final picture, the line $AB$ has been rotated to $AB'$ so that the displacement from the $AB'_A$ point to $AB'_B$ is $(x,y)$, the same as the original displacement from $A$ to $B$. But the center is still at $(\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)$, so it follows that the two ends of the line are at

$$AB'_A=(\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)-\frac12(x,y),\qquad AB'_B=(\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2},0)+\frac12(x,y)$$

and in particular, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $AB'_A$ are $b=\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\frac12x$ and $a=-\frac12y$.